# Why changing numpy array to tf.data.Dataset risis an error on keras model training

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying a simple training on dataset created from array.

See:

```
import numpy as np
import gc
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import os

values = np.array([[0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,1]])
results = np.array([[0], [1], [1], [0]])

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((values, results))
dataset

>>>> <TensorSliceDataset shapes: ((2,), (1,)), types: (tf.int32, tf.int32)>

# Build a simple model
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.Input(shape=(2,)))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')) # , kernel_initializer='he_uniform'
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

print("Fit on dataset/NumPy data")
history = model.fit(dataset, epochs=10)

>>>> ...
>>>> ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 2 but received input with shape (2, 1)
```

What am I doing wrong?

The same with just numpy arrays works!

Comment: You need to batch your dataset. Example: `dataset = dataset.batch(16)`

Comment: Hi @neojg, Could you please check as mentioned in the above comment by Frightera and let us know if the issue still persists? Thanks!